# Sharepoint Visual Web Part does not have a .cs file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sdk, web-parts

I am trying to create a visual web part that has some properties associated with it so that I can use them as settings for the web part. I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188019/Creating-Visual-Web-Part-Properties) however whenever I create a new "Visual Web Part" project it does not create the .cs file that they refer to in the tutorial.

Instead it creates the following:

- Elements.xml
- WebpartName.ascx
- WebpartName.ascx.cs
- WebpartName.ascx.g.cs
- WebpartName.webpart

I am guessing that this is related to the SDK that I have installed:

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 SDK - version 14.0.4763.1086

Am I doing something wrong or should I try to get a different version of the SDK or is there a way that I can introduce webpart properties using this type of file structure? All of the examples I have seen thus far refer to the "WebpartName.cs" file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that Sharepoint 2013 Visual Web Part does not have a .cs file, but you can still add custom properties to the visual webpart using the .ascx.cs file.

Please refer the attached link for detailed steps:

http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-create-a-custom-property-and-set-a-default-value-in-a-SharePoint-2013-Visual-WebPart

Regards,
Deepali